# Kernel and header Version not the same

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi-os, driver, software-compilation

So i wanted to build the driver for my wifi adapter for my raspberry pi 400: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702
And i did everything what was said and then got the error: `Your kernel files are not properly installed.` So i send in my issue there and I was told the kernel and header version has to be the same. My kernel version is 6.1.21-v8+ and my header version is 6.1.21+. Now how do i fix this (I tried sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel and raspberrypi-kernel-headers already but didnt help.

Comment: what's the result of `ls -l /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build` - did you install 64bit pi OS, or are you just running the 64bit kernel with 32bit "userland"

Comment: @JaromandaX there is no build foler in there but im using raspberrypi os 32bit lite

Comment: oh yeah ... 32bit OS but enabling 64bit kernel ... I remember that being annoying for installing the headers. though, it looks like you don't have headers installed anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX can i fix this somehow?

Comment: to be honest, I don't think you can compile 64bit drivers in 32bit OS - either don't enable the 64bit kernel, or switch to 64bit OS (that's a re-install, there's no migration to it as far as I know)

Comment: You could try the following ... `wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/raspberrypi-kernel-headers_1.20230405-1_arm64.deb` then `sudo dpkg -i --force-all raspberrypi-kernel-headers_1.20230405-1_arm64.deb` - it may break things, if it does you get to keep both pieces

Comment: @JaromandaX now it atleast started the script but with this error: Building module:
cleaning build area...
./dkms-make.sh...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.21-v8+ (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.13.1/build/make.log for more information.
An error occurred. dkms build error:  10
Please report this error.
Please copy all screen output and paste it into the problem report.
Run the following before reattempting installation.
$ sudo ./remove-driver.sh

Comment: I'd run https://github.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source and build the kernel source tree that way.

Comment: as I said, it may break things, or at least not work as you've found. 64bit kernel + 32bit userland has always been fiddly to work with. Either switch to full 64bit (as mentioned, would required a complete re-install) or stick to 32bit - since the pi 400 only has 4GB RAM (if I recall) then there's no significant benefit of running the 64bit kernel anyway